# Vue js apply filter on v-model in an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs, vue.js

Hope someone can help me! I have made a directive wrapping the Jasny Bootstrap Plugin more specifically the input-mask thing and everything goes well!

Now I have made a custom filter supported by moment to format the date field!

The date format that I receive from my backend application is YYY-MM-DD and I must show on the view as DD/MM/YYYY... I've tried `v-model="date | myDate"` but it didn't work properly!

**JS**

```
Vue.directive('input-mask', {
  params: ['mask'],

  bind: function() {
    $(this.el).inputmask({
      mask: this.params.mask
    });

  },
});

Vue.filter('my-date', function(value, formatString) {

  if (value != undefined)
    return '';

  if (formatString != undefined)
    return moment(value).format(formatString);

  return moment(value).format('DD/MM/YYYY');

});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    date: '2015-06-26',
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<label>Date</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-input-mask mask="99/99/9999" v-model="date">
<p>{{ date | myDate 'dd/mm/yyyy' }}</p>
```

There is the [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/yayuyo/edit?html,js,output) if somebody's interested!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: Explaining better what I expect =)**

When the page first load the input receive the value of 2015-06-26 and I would like to show that value as DD/MM/YYYY so 26/06/2015! It works properly only after I start typing something!

Comment: "it didn't work properly" is not descriptive enough.  Please explain *how* it didn't work properly.  What did you expect, and what did it do instead?

Comment: Sorry @MattJohnson! Just added a better explanation on the bottom! See if you understand please!

Comment: Note that d/m/y and m/d/y are ambiguous, much better to use the month name like `10-Apr-2016`.

Comment: @RobG In some parts of the world (Italy, for example) d/m/y is commonplace and everything else just rises confusion among users.

Comment: @MarcoBolis—agree completely, m/d/y is used by only a small minority. But it's pervasive in computing (and particularly the web), so disambiguating by using the month name is helpful.

Comment: @RobG You make a point

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I understand what you are trying to do, however, because of the two way binding when using v-model, it may be better to just format the date as you receive it from the server, and then, use it with the desired format in your front-end app (`'DD/MM/YYYY'`).

When sending the data back to the back-end, you just format it back to the desired server format (`'YYYY-MM-DD'`).

In your Vue app, the work flow would be something like this:

```
 new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    data: {
      date: null,
    },
    methods: {
        getDataFromServer: function() {
                // Ajax call to get data from server

                // Let's pretend the received date data was saved in a variable (serverDate)
                // We will hardcode it for this ex.
                var serverDate = '2015-06-26';

                // Format it and save to vue data property
                this.date = this.frontEndDateFormat(serverDate);
        },
        saveDataToServer: function() {
            // Format data first before sending it back to server
            var serverDate = this.backEndDateFormat(this.date);

            // Ajax call sending formatted data (serverDate)
        },
        frontEndDateFormat: function(date) {
            return moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
        },
        backEndDateFormat: function(date) {
            return moment(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        }
    }
  });
```

This works well for me, hope it helps.

Here is a fiddle for it:

https://jsfiddle.net/crabbly/xoLwkog9/

Syntax UPDATE:

```
    ...
    methods: {
        getDataFromServer() {
                // Ajax call to get data from server

                // Let's pretend the received date data was saved in a variable (serverDate)
                // We will hardcode it for this ex.
                const serverDate = '2015-06-26'

                // Format it and save to vue data property
                this.date = this.frontEndDateFormat(serverDate)
        },
        saveDataToServer() {
            // Format data first before sending it back to server
            const serverDate = this.backEndDateFormat(this.date)

            // Ajax call sending formatted data (serverDate)
        },
        frontEndDateFormat(date) {
            return moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
        },
        backEndDateFormat(date) {
            return moment(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        }
    }
  })
```

Comment: The OP wants "DD/MM/YYYY", not 'MM/DD/YYYY' (though since both are ambiguous, using the month name or abbreviation would be clearer).

Comment: @RobG Thank you, just edited it. Typo here. Moment will accept his desired format as long it is explicit.

Comment: Not sure the state of Vue in 2016. But we can use `computed` property to achieve this, the code will be much simpler.

Comment: @RosdiKasim Computed properties were available in Vue since v1. However, I wouldn't recommend using them in this scenario. There is no need to keep two reactive format versions for each date, at least for the purpose above. What I would recommend instead, is to move those date formatters into a utility es6 module, making them reusable across other components. It would also clean the above component as well.

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar problem when I wanted to uppercase an input value.

This is what I ended up doing:

```
// create a directive to transform the model value
Vue.directive('uppercase', {
  twoWay: true, // this transformation applies back to the vm
  bind: function () {
    this.handler = function () {
      this.set(this.el.value.toUpperCase());
    }.bind(this);
    this.el.addEventListener('input', this.handler);
  },
  unbind: function () {
    this.el.removeEventListener('input', this.handler);
  }
});
```

Then I can use this directive on the input field with a `v-model`.

```
<input type="text" v-model="someData" v-uppercase="someData">
```

Now, whenever I type into this field or change `someData`, the value is transformed to uppercase.

This essentially did the same thing as I hoped `v-model="someData | uppercase"` would do. But of course, you can't do that.

In summation: make a *directive that transforms the data, not a filter*.

Comment: directive works when page is loaded or user types in text. When UI is refreshed due to change in other controls， update method on directive won't be invoked. The value in textbox will be reverted to unformatted one.

Comment: @flyfrog I think a better choice here would be a `computed` property

Comment: @flyfrog you can use _inserted_ option to invoke directive onload. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Hook-Functions

Answer (score 14):

Go to main.js and add the following code :

```
import moment from 'moment'
Vue.filter('myDate', function (value) {
    if (value) {
        return moment(String(value)).format('dd/mm/yyyy')
    }
});
```

In your HTML do the following :

```
<label>Date</label>
<v-text-field :value="date | myDate" @input="value=>date=value"></v-text-field>
<p>{{ date | myDate 'dd/mm/yyyy' }}</p>
```

So we used above v-bind to bind the value and @input event handler to have the v-model functionality.

Comment: I dont know why this isn't the chosen answer. This perfectly solves OP problem the way he wanted. I wasn't sure if it was going to work but it turns out it was this simple. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you this helps keep separation of concern. Played around with view models, but this is a much better solution then VM's.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I implemented a vue filter for a v-model using the watch callback, this won't update the value on load.

```
Vue.filter('uppercase', function (value) {
    return value.toUpperCase();
});
```

The html:

```
<input type="text" v-model="someData">
```

And the watch callback:

```
watch:{
   someData(val) {
       this.someData = this.$options.filters.uppercase(val);
    },
}
```

Comment: Very useful! To avoid _recursive call_ in the watch function, first get the filtered value, compare it to the current one and **only set if different**. `if (this.someData != filteredVal) this.someData = filteredVal`

Answer (score 2):

When you get the value initially, adjust it to fit the input.  I got it working in the `ready` function, but you could do this after your DB call as well:

```
ready: function(){    
  var year = this.date.substr(0, 4);
  var monDay = this.date.substr(5,5);
  var result = monDay + "-" + year;
  this.date = result.replace(/-/g,"/");
}
```

You may have to do something similar on the way back up to your database as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to offer an alternative, with the hook update from Vue-directive

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      someData: '',
    }
  },
  directives: {
    lowercase: {
      update(el) {
        el.value = el.value.toLowerCase()
      },
    },
    uppercase: {
      update(el) {
        el.value = el.value.toUpperCase()
      },
    },
    capitalize: {
      update(el) {
        const lowerCase = el.value.toLowerCase()
        el.value = lowerCase.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lowerCase.slice(1)
      },
    },
  },
}
```

or

```
Vue.directive('lowercase', {
  update(el) {
    el.value = el.value.toLowerCase()
  }
})
Vue.directive('uppercase', {
  update(el) {
    el.value = el.value.toUpperCase()
  }
})
Vue.directive('capitalize', {
  update(el) {
    const lowerCase = el.value.toLowerCase()
    el.value = lowerCase.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lowerCase.slice(1)
  }
})
```

```
<input type="text" v-model="someData" v-capitalize />
```

Answer (score 0):

Template

```
<input type="text" v-model="date" @change="onDateChange">
```

Component

```
  methods: {
    onDateChange(event) {
      this.myDate = event.target.value
    }
    getFormatedDate(date) {
     return '2020/08/19'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    date() {
      return this.getFormatedDate(this.myDate)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use value for bind on text field
example:

```
<v-text-field :value="string | stringFormat"></v-text-field>
```

Answer (score -1):

I've found that I can filter input using the ordinary component `v-bind:value` / `v-on:input` dance without resorting to `data` or `watch` clauses if I just call `$forceUpdate()` after emitting the filtered value:

The Vue component:

```js
{
  props: ['value'],
  methods: {
    mEmit: function(EVT) {
      const VAL      = EVT.target.value;
      var   FILTERED = myFilterFunction(VAL);
      this.$emit('input', FILTERED);
      this.$forceUpdate();
    }
  }
}
```

The component HTML (data is filtered as it is entered):

```html
  <input type="text" v-bind:value="value" v-on:input="mEmit($event)" />
```

Using the component:

```html
<my-component v-model="myDataVar"></my-component>
```