# How can I convert a long list of 'watch' into a functional way in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, watch

I'm a novice for vueJS.
I have a long list of watch list. It's all same.
But I don't know how to convert them into a functional way.

They are all for adding comma in input tag and v-model.
It works very well. But the codes look very dumb because they are exactly the same, but not their name.

```
new Vue({
  data: {
    tmp_price1: '',
    tmp_price2: '',
    tmp_price3: '',
    tmp_a_price: '',
    tmp_b_price: '',
  },

  watch: {
   tmp_price1: function(newValue) {
     if (newValue != '') {
       const result = newValue.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
       Vue.nextTick(() => this.tmp_price1 = result);
     }
   },
   tmp_price2: function(newValue) {
     if (newValue != '') {
       const result = newValue.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
       Vue.nextTick(() => this.tmp_price2 = result);
     }
   },

  ....(repeat)

  },
```

Please help me improve these dumb codes efficient way.

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: In fact, I tried twice your answer cause it looks the easiest one. But I'll try again tonight. (sorry it's a running service so I can't do this now..!_! )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may seem like over-engineering, but I would probably make a component to encapsulate the commafying behavior. The component would have a settable computed in it that emits the commafied value for the parent to use in updating.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tmp_price1: '',
    tmp_price2: '',
    tmp_price3: '',
    tmp_a_price: '',
    tmp_b_price: '',
  },
  components: {
    commafiedInput: {
      props: ['value'],
      template: '<input v-model="commaValue">',
      computed: {
        commaValue: {
          get() {
            return this.value;
          },
          set(newValue) {
            this.$emit('input', this.addCommas(newValue));
          }
        }
      },
      methods: {
        addCommas(v) {
          return v.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div> {{tmp_price1}}
    <commafied-input v-model="tmp_price1"></commafied-input>
  </div>
  <commafied-input v-model="tmp_price2"></commafied-input>
  <commafied-input v-model="tmp_price3"></commafied-input>
  <commafied-input v-model="tmp_a_price"></commafied-input>
  <commafied-input v-model="tmp_b_price"></commafied-input>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this solution but it didn't work....I think I made a mistake. It keeps getting me an error message like 'Uncaught TypeError: this.addCommas is not a function..'.

Comment: I copied the whole 'components' section from here and pasted it into my codes... what did I miss here..?

Comment: I do not know. Is something outside the `commafiedInput` calling `addCommas`?

Comment: OMG..I tried again, and it suddenly magically works! I probably had made some mistakes before. Thank you!

Comment: Can I ask an another question? What if I have a variable like 'tmp_prices' as an array, how can I change this?

Comment: You can use `v-for="price in tmp_prices"` with the `commafied-input` tag. You would `v-model="price"` then.

Comment: Thank you. And.. I found it has a weird problem. I applied this code to another files(they're almost same structure) and it doesn't work. I don't know why... !_!

Answer (score 0):

Just displaying the formatted version of the value can be done with a simple filter:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tmp_price1: '123123',
    tmp_price2: '',
    tmp_price3: ''
  },
  filters: {
    myFilter(v) {
      return v.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }   
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div><input v-model="tmp_price1">{{tmp_price1 | myFilter}}</div>
  <div><input v-model="tmp_price2">{{tmp_price2 | myFilter}}</div>
  <div><input v-model="tmp_price3">{{tmp_price3 | myFilter}}</div>
  
</div>
```

...but that's not enough for the input fields; you can't just throw a filter onto the `v-model` attribute.  A sub-component as described in [Roy J's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53904294/3412322) is probably the best and most reusable way to handle that, but if you're ok with something a bit quick-and-dirty (but not *too* dirty) you could just throw a change handler at the problem:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tmp_price1: '123123',
    tmp_price2: '',
    tmp_price3: ''
  },
  methods: {
    myFormatter(fieldname) {
      /* replace the user's input with the formatted value.
      
          There's probably some clever way to read the v-model 
          name from the input field instead of passing it to the 
          method as a string, but I'm not going to mess around 
          with that for what is after all a quick-and-dirty technique */
      this[fieldname] = this[fieldname].replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // if the initial values aren't always empty, you'll need to run the
    // formatter function on component load as well as on user input:
    ['tmp_price1', 'tmp_price2', 'tmp_price3'].forEach(f => {
      this.myFormatter(f);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div><input v-model="tmp_price1" @input="myFormatter('tmp_price1')">{{tmp_price1}}</div>
  <div><input v-model="tmp_price2" @input="myFormatter('tmp_price2')">{{tmp_price2}}</div>
  <div><input v-model="tmp_price3" @input="myFormatter('tmp_price3')">{{tmp_price3}}</div>
</div>
```

(Or as another variation, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38797052/3412322) to a similar question uses essentially the same technique, but wraps it in a Vue directive to bind the input events instead of attaching `@input` handlers.)

Note that in the "filter" version, the `v-model` values remain the original user input; the filter only affects the displayed value.  In the second example the formatting is applied to the `v-model`ed values themselves, so if you pass those values on to somewhere else you'll get the formatted version. Both techniques can be useful, depending on the circumstances.  (Or you could even use them in combination -- remove non-digits in the v-model, then add the commas via a filter just for display, for example.)